Add top most label to the center of Spinning wheel in UIKit
I'm working on an assignment in the Swift language. I'm trying to achieve functionality where I have a spinning wheel view and multiple labels are added as items around the wheel. I can rotate the spinning view with a swipe gesture in both directions, left or right. I'm able to achieve the whole functionality.
Now the problem is that I want the top most label to be in the center of the spinning wheel arrow. Or in other words, I want to set any specific label index in the center of the spinning wheel. The functionality is working fine if I have an even number of items like 2 or 4, but facing issues if the number of items are 3 or 5.
Code I'm using for add arrow in spinning wheel is:
var currentRotation: CGFloat = 0.0
var currentIndex = 0.0
var selectedIndex = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var spinningView: UIView!

private func addLabelsToSpinningView() {
    let labelCount = viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?.count ?? 0
    let angleInterval = CGFloat.pi * 2 / CGFloat(labelCount ) // Divide the circle equally among labels
    let labelWidth: CGFloat = 120
    let labelHeight: CGFloat = 100
    
    let radiusFactor: CGFloat = 0.8 // Adjust this factor to bring labels closer or farther
    for view in self.spinningView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.currentIndex = selectedIndex
    self.lastIndex = (self.viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?.count ?? 0) - 1
    self.modeLabels.removeAll()
    for labelIndex in 0..<labelCount {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = self.viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?[labelIndex].name
        label.numberOfLines = 0 // Single line of text for horizontal labels
        label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        label.textAlignment = .center
        if labelIndex == self.selectedIndex {
            label.font = AppFont.getAppFont(fontName: .manropeExtraBold, fontSize: 20.0)
        } else {
            label.font = AppFont.getAppFont(fontName: .manropeRegular, fontSize: 17.0)
        }
        
        // Calculate the angle for the label
        let labelAngle = CGFloat(labelIndex) * angleInterval + CGFloat.pi / 2  // Start from top radians
        
        // Calculate the position of the label around the spinning view
        let radius = self.spinningView.bounds.width * radiusFactor / 2 // Adjusted radius                
        let labelCenterX = self.spinningView.bounds.midX + radius * cos(labelAngle)
        let labelCenterY = self.spinningView.bounds.midY + radius * sin(labelAngle)
        
        // Create a frame for the label
        let labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)
        label.frame = labelFrame
        label.center = CGPoint(x: labelCenterX, y: labelCenterY)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        self.spinningView.addSubview(label)
        self.modeLabels.append(label)
        
        // Rotate the label
        label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: labelAngle + CGFloat.pi / 2) // Offset by pi/2 to make it horizontal
    }
    
    let labelArray: CGFloat = CGFloat((self.viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?.count ?? 0))
    let rotationAngle: CGFloat = ((-CGFloat.pi * 2)/labelArray) * (labelArray/2)
    if self.selectedIndex > 0 && self.selectedIndex <= 2 && self.selectedIndex != 1{
        self.currentRotation = rotationAngle * CGFloat(self.selectedIndex)
    } else if self.selectedIndex > 2  || self.selectedIndex == 1 {
        self.currentRotation = (CGFloat.pi * 2)/labelArray * CGFloat(self.selectedIndex)
    }else {
        self.currentRotation = rotationAngle
    }
    
    debugPrint("rotationAngle on Add labels ------>>>> ", self.currentRotation)
    self.spinningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
}

I have added the code for how I'm adding the swipe gesture to the spinning wheel. Also, the swipe functionality is working in the wheel view. The case is the very first time I want a default value as starting index of the wheel, and after user spin every index that is selected that should be in the top center of the wheel.
Another case is if the top selected feature is not enabled from the backend side, the wheel will again move the last selected item. E.g user select the 4th item and the last selected item was 3. But 4th item is not enabled, So now the wheel will rotate to the last selected item that was 3, If user spin again to the same direction, It should mov to next item that will be item 5.
Code for setup Spinning Wheel and add Swipe gesture to it:
private func addWheelView() {
    spinningView.layer.cornerRadius = spinningView.frame.size.height / 2
    let swipeLeftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeLeftGesture.direction = .left
    swipeGestureview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGesture)
    let swipeRightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeRightGesture.direction = .right
    swipeGestureview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGesture)
    addLabelsToSpinningView()
}

Code for Spin the wheel:
@objc func handleSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let labelArray: CGFloat = CGFloat(viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?.count ?? 0)
    let rotationAngle: CGFloat = gesture.direction == .left ? (-CGFloat.pi * 2)/labelArray : (CGFloat.pi * 2)/labelArray
   
        currentRotation += rotationAngle debugPrint("rotationAngle", rotationAngle)
    
    if gesture.direction == .left && currentIndex != lastIndex {
        currentIndex += 1
    }else if gesture.direction == .right && currentIndex != firstIndex {
        currentIndex -= 1
    }else if (gesture.direction == .left ||  gesture.direction == .right) && currentIndex == lastIndex {
        currentIndex = firstIndex
    }else if (gesture.direction == .left ||  gesture.direction == .right) && currentIndex == firstIndex {
        currentIndex = lastIndex
    }
    print("SELECTED INDEX ----->>> \(viewModel.selectedIndex)")
    print("Current INDEX ----->>> \(currentIndex)")
   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.spinningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
        self.dashedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
        self.updateMoodLabels(index: self.currentIndex)
    }
}
    
func updateMoodLabels(index: Int) {
    for i in 0..<modeLabels.count {
            if index == i {
                modeLabels[i].font = AppFont.getAppFont(fontName: .manropeExtraBold, fontSize: 20.0)
            } else {
                modeLabels[i].font = AppFont.getAppFont(fontName: .manropeRegular, fontSize: 17.0)
            }
    }
}

Please let me know if more details required.
I'm facing an issue with below code, Actually apart from the Swipe gesture I also want to update the wheel item with the help of two buttons -(Left/Right)
I'm using the same function for update the wheel using button
@IBAction func didTapRightButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.currentGestureDirection = .right
        let swipeRightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
        swipeRightGesture.direction = .right
        self.handleSwipe(swipeRightGesture)
}


Hmm... I added enough code to implement the code you posted, and this is what I get with 3, 4, 5 or 6 labels: https://i.sstatic.net/NdXol.png

@DonMag, I want the same output that you are showing in attached screenshot. But not getting the same result. As you can see in the above image, I load 5 items in the spinning wheel, but still the top most item is not in the center. Actually The issue is for the very first time items might be in center, but it will change its top center  as you rotate the wheel in any direction. Can you please share your code, how you achieve the same. One more thing I want to set any index item as a top item of the spinning wheel. Please help me in the same. Thanks for your response.

"it will change its top center as you rotate the wheel" -- you didn't include any code showing how you are rotating the wheel ... if you add that, maybe we can figure out what's going wrong. As far as "set any index item as a top item" -- that depends ... do you want to animate an index to the top? Or, do you want to start with an index at the top?

@DonMag, In the very start I want to set any default item index as top of the wheel, And after that when the weel is rotated, I want the item that is selected should animate to top center of the wheel. For more details I have edited my Code, Please have a look, And thans again for your response.

First, at couple tips:

you have a lot going on here. It's best to ask about a single task, rather than multiple tasks.
don't use things like viewModel.homeDataModel or AppFont.getAppFont ... makes it difficult to build and run your code when we have to guess at things
strip your code down to minimal, reproducible and runnable code. You should post a full example view controller that we can copy/paste/run.


So, to answer your first question...
When you "build" your spinningView, always add the labels with Zero rotation transform, starting at the Top (12 o'clock position).
Then, if you want to start with, say index 2 at the top, after you've added and positioned (and rotated) the individual labels, set the rotation transform on the view.

For your question about "disabled" items, think about this logic:

determine if the Next index is enabled or not

if enabled

rotate to the Next index


if not enabled

if firstAttempt

rotate to the Next index, and then
"bounce back" to currentIndex
else

step through to find the next enabled index
rotate to the That index






then, update current/selected index properties as needed




So, here is some example code that you can copy/paste/run without making any edits:
struct MoodStruct {
    var name: String = ""
    var enabled: Bool = true
}

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var currentRotation: CGFloat = 0.0
    var currentIndex = 0
    var selectedIndex = 0
    var firstIndex = 0
    var lastIndex: Int = 0
    
    // track attempt to spin to disabled mood
    var firstAttempt: Bool = true

    let spinningView = UIView()
    let dashedImageView = UIView()

    let swipeGestureview = UIView()
    
    let sampleData: [String] = [
        "Happy", "Sad", "Angry",
        "Silly", "Lonely", "Excited",
        "Thrilled", "Meh",
    ]
    
    var moodData: [MoodStruct] = []
    
    var moodLabels: [UILabel] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        spinningView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(spinningView)
        dashedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(dashedImageView)

        swipeGestureview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(swipeGestureview)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            spinningView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            spinningView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            spinningView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
            spinningView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.widthAnchor),
            
            dashedImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.centerYAnchor),
            dashedImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.centerXAnchor),
            dashedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.widthAnchor),
            dashedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.heightAnchor),
            
            swipeGestureview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.centerYAnchor),
            swipeGestureview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.centerXAnchor),
            swipeGestureview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.widthAnchor),
            swipeGestureview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spinningView.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        spinningView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        // don't set this greater than the "moods" array count
        let numMoods = 7

        moodData = []
        for i in 0..<numMoods {
            let aMood = MoodStruct(name: "\(sampleData[i]) \(i)", enabled: true)
            moodData.append(aMood)
        }
        
        // let's start with mood 2 selected
        selectedIndex = 2
        
        // for a test, let's set moods 4 & 5 to disabled
        moodData[4].enabled = false
        moodData[5].enabled = false

        swipeGestureview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let dashedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        dashedLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        dashedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        dashedLayer.lineWidth = 2
        dashedLayer.lineDashPattern = [8, 8]
        dashedLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: dashedImageView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 75.0, dy: 75.0)).cgPath
        dashedImageView.layer.addSublayer(dashedLayer)
        
        addWheelView()
        
    }
    private func addLabelsToSpinningView() {
        let labelCount = moodData.count
        let angleInterval = CGFloat.pi * 2 / CGFloat(labelCount ) // Divide the circle equally among labels
        let labelWidth: CGFloat = 120
        let labelHeight: CGFloat = 100
        
        let radiusFactor: CGFloat = 0.8 // Adjust this factor to bring labels closer or farther
        for view in self.spinningView.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        self.lastIndex = moodData.count - 1 // (self.viewModel.homeDataModel?.data?.result?.count ?? 0) - 1
        self.moodLabels.removeAll()
        for labelIndex in 0..<labelCount {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = moodData[labelIndex].name
            label.numberOfLines = 0 // Single line of text for horizontal labels
            label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
            label.textAlignment = .center
            
            // Calculate the angle for the label
            // Start from top radians
            let labelAngle = CGFloat(labelIndex) * angleInterval - CGFloat.pi / 2
            
            // Calculate the position of the label around the spinning view
            let radius = self.spinningView.bounds.width * radiusFactor / 2 // Adjusted radius
            let labelCenterX = self.spinningView.bounds.midX + radius * cos(labelAngle)
            let labelCenterY = self.spinningView.bounds.midY + radius * sin(labelAngle)
            
            // Create a frame for the label
            let labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)
            label.frame = labelFrame
            label.center = CGPoint(x: labelCenterX, y: labelCenterY)
            label.clipsToBounds = true
            self.spinningView.addSubview(label)
            self.moodLabels.append(label)
            
            // Rotate the label
            label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: labelAngle + CGFloat.pi / 2) // Offset by pi/2 to make it horizontal
        }
        
        // rotate so selectedIndex is at top
        self.currentIndex = self.selectedIndex
        self.currentRotation = -(CGFloat(self.selectedIndex) * angleInterval)
        self.spinningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
        self.dashedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)

        debugPrint("rotationAngle on Add labels ------>>>> ", self.currentRotation)
    }
    
    private func addWheelView() {
        spinningView.layer.cornerRadius = spinningView.frame.size.height / 2
        let swipeLeftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        swipeLeftGesture.direction = .left
        swipeGestureview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGesture)
        let swipeRightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        swipeRightGesture.direction = .right
        swipeGestureview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGesture)
        addLabelsToSpinningView()
        
        // update the fonts of the mood labels
        updateMoodLabels(index: self.selectedIndex)
    }
    
    @objc func handleSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let labelCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(moodData.count)
        var angleInterval = CGFloat.pi * 2 / labelCount // Divide the circle equally among labels
        
        var toRot: CGFloat = 0
        
        var bounceBack: Bool = false
        
        var toIndex: Int = 0
        
        var numSlots: CGFloat = 0
        
        // determine if the Next index is enabled or not
        //  if not
        //      if firstAttempt
        //          rotate to the Next index, and then
        //          "bounce back" to currentIndex
        //      else
        //          step through to find the next enabled index
        //          rotate to the That index
        //
        //  update selected / current index properties

        if gesture.direction == .left {
            
            angleInterval *= -1.0
            toIndex = currentIndex + 1
            if !moodData[toIndex % moodData.count].enabled {
                if firstAttempt {
                    bounceBack = true
                    firstAttempt = false
                } else {
                    while !moodData[toIndex % moodData.count].enabled {
                        toIndex += 1
                    }
                }
            }
            
            numSlots = CGFloat(toIndex - self.currentIndex)
            toRot = self.currentRotation + (numSlots * angleInterval)
            
        } else {
            
            toIndex = currentIndex - 1
            if !moodData[abs(toIndex % moodData.count)].enabled {
                if firstAttempt {
                    bounceBack = true
                    firstAttempt = false
                } else {
                    while !moodData[abs(toIndex % moodData.count)].enabled {
                        toIndex -= 1
                    }
                }
            }
            
            numSlots = CGFloat(toIndex - self.currentIndex)
            toRot = self.currentRotation - (numSlots * angleInterval)
            
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5 * abs(numSlots), animations: {
            self.spinningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: toRot)
            self.dashedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: toRot)
            if toIndex < 0 {
                self.updateMoodLabels(index: self.moodData.count + toIndex)
            } else {
                self.updateMoodLabels(index: toIndex % self.moodData.count)
            }
        }, completion: { _ in
            if bounceBack {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    self.spinningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
                    self.dashedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.currentRotation)
                    self.updateMoodLabels(index: self.currentIndex)
                })
            } else {
                self.firstAttempt = true
                self.currentRotation = toRot
                if toIndex < 0 {
                    toIndex = self.moodData.count + toIndex
                }
                self.currentIndex = toIndex % self.moodData.count
                self.updateMoodLabels(index: self.currentIndex)
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    func updateMoodLabels(index: Int) {
        for i in 0..<moodLabels.count {
            if index == i && moodData[i].enabled {
                moodLabels[i].font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
            } else {
                moodLabels[i].font = .systemFont(ofSize: 19.0, weight: .regular)
            }
            moodLabels[i].textColor = moodData[i].enabled ? .black : .red
        }
    }
}


Keep in mind: this is Example Code Only!!! It has little-to-no error checking (for things like array bounds), and I tried to keep most of your code vars / properties -- although I didn't put in any time trying to optimize anything.

The above code is working, but i need a little more help, Actually now I'm trying to handle the wheel state with left/right button, Swipe is working fine with the left button,  but when i try to swipe to right and there is only one mood item is enabled, I'm facing issue with that. In that case the wheel is moved to any random item that is not even enabled. Could you please help me in in the same.

@Gurmeetkaur - if you have only one mood item enabled you should probably disable swiping. If you don't want to do that... if you have only a single mood enabled, don't set firstAttempt = false.
